# How to know the type of a native SQL query result in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a native SQL query in Hibernate. I get the query result by :
`List l = query.list()`.

I know that each element of the list corresponds to a line of the result table. But what are the types of those elements ?

Java tells me they are of type : Object. Ok but I want more. Because I want to print the results in the Eclipse console. But for that, I have to know the types, I have to know what this list exactly contains.

Here is the result table of my query I get in SL Developer :

[image: Result table as shown in SQL Developer]

**And know, I want to print all that data in Eclipse console**

In Eclipse, I use `Query query = session.createSQlQuery("my query");`
List l = query.list();`

For information, here is the SQL query code : [image: my query]

Comment: Depends on the underlying table structure. Can you tell us how do you "print" the results (because `System.out.println()` can handle `Object`)?

Comment: I print the results by the following commands :  `System.out.println(l.get(0));`  `System.out.println(l.get(1));`...  But it prints some weird things like that :(`java.lang.Object;@4b41587d`)

Comment: The fact is I need to know what `l.get(0)` is. It corresponds to the first line of the result table, ok. But then ? How to print the data corresponding to the different columns ?

Comment: Ok, I will do that, thanks.

Comment: I edited my question. Can you check the link to see the table structure ? The fact is how do I print the data in Eclipse console ? I know the type of each column but I can't know the type of `l.get(0)` because it's a line. So it's an object, but how to access the 3 columns of that line ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly by table structure ? Do you mean the actual SQL code of the query ? I edited my question to add the code.

Comment: Sorry, seems I need 20 reputation to talk there...

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. See my answer

Answer (score 3):

The `Object` in the list is an array of `Object`s (one per column).

You have to iterate (that's for each row) then use the array of columns:

```
final List<Object> l = query.list();
for (final Object row : l) {
    final Object[] columns = (Object[]) row;
    // use columns[0],  columns[1] etc
    System.out.println(columns[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've got your issue correct, try `getClass().getName()` methods, which'll give you runtime class of your object. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())